# I can't install nginx 1.22.1 from the official repository

Tags: nginx, repository, oraclelinux

I have a VM on Oracle Linux 8.8
I need to install nginx-1.22.1, but only version nginx-1.14.1 can be installed from the official repository:

```
https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/x86_64/index.html
```

This version nginx-1.22.1 is present in this repository.
Also this repository is enabled:

```
[ol8_appstream]
name=Oracle Linux 8 Application Stream ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

I have executed the commands:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache
```

But after executed:

```
yum install nginx
```

the yum manager can only install version 1.14.1:

```
nginx     x86_64     1:1.14.1-9.0.1.module+el8.0.0+5347+9282027e
```

Can you help me?

I do not know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Oracle Linux 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/software-management/sfw-mgmt-InstallSoftwareonEnterpriseLinux.html#appstream) on modules and Application Streams:

```
sudo dnf module enable nginx:1.22
sudo dnf install nginx
```